# Convert NSSet into an Array

Tags: swift, core-data, nsarray, nsset

I'm storing data in a CoreData entity that uses relationships. By default a `toMany` type relationship will be of type`NSSet`. In order to load this `NSSet` into a tableview in the order in which the items where added to this `NSSet` I need to convert it to an array. How do I go about achieving this?

[image]

NSManaged Subclass generated:

```
extension Node {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Node> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Node>(entityName: "Node")
    }

    @NSManaged public var value: String?
    @NSManaged public var children: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var parent: Node?


    @objc(addChildrenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChildren(_ value: Node)

    @objc(removeChildrenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChildren(_ value: Node)

    @objc(addChildren:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChildren(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeChildren:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChildren(_ values: NSSet)
}
```

Note: As CloudKit doesn't support ordered relationships, I can't use ordered arrangement as a part of the solution.

Comment: Do you want to convert the relationship to ordered or do you want to sort a `NSSet` into an `Array` in code?

Comment: I want to convert the ```NSSet``` to an array( in the order in which the items where added to the ```NSSet```).

Comment: @RajaKishan wouldn't that create an array of type [NSSet?]. I'm trying to get an array of type [Node]

Comment: ```let arr = Array(children!) ``` try this

Comment: Well, that creates an array but it isn't ordered.

Comment: core-data always use NSSet. You cant create an array. You have to sort the again array.

Comment: You said in your previous question that you used `sorted()`, why isn't that working for you?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ```sorted()``` cannot be used to order a ```NSSet``` in order in which the items added. As for my previous question I wasn't aware that this was the case at the time.

Comment: So that is your real problem? If you need to maintain the order in which items have been added then you need to check the Ordered check box for the relationship in the model builder or add an attribute that keeps track of the order like a counter or a date attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use ordered relationships as I mentioned in the latest edit to the question. As for the latter suggestion, I'm giving that a try now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to declare the relationship as **non-optional** native Swift type

```
@NSManaged public var children: Set<Node>
```

To get an array just `sort` the set. This is pretty easy with a Swift `Set`. As a set is unordered by definition you have to do that anyway to get a fixed order. Assuming you have a `dateAdded` attribute you can write

```
let sortedChildren = children.sorted{$0.dateAdded > $1.dateAdded}
```

Comment: As I'm using CloudKit I can't use a ordered relationship. Would sorting the  ```NSSet``` work regardless?

Comment: The relationship is unordered. `Set` and `NSSet` behave very similar. Core Data including CloudKit works very well with native types.

Comment: Why non-optional, not all nodes must have children (or a parent)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I *vote* for non-optional collection types whenever possible. There is no difference to check for `nil` or for empty set. In a *tree* you will probably create a computed property `var isLeaf : Bool { return children.isEmpty }` anyway. Of course the `parent` node must be an optional if it can be `nil`.